# what's wrong with this javascript script.?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am trying to learn javascript by following this exercise from MDN website [Learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/A_first_splash)

here is my final code for the game.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Number guessing game</title>

  <style>
    html {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    body {
      width: 50%;
      max-width: 800px;
      min-width: 480px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .lastResult {
      color: white;
      padding: 3px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Number guessing game</h1>

  <p>We have selected a random number between 1 and 100. See if you can guess it in 10 turns or less. We'll tell you if your guess was too high or too low.</p>


  <div class="form">
    <label for="guessField">Enter a guess:</label>
    <input type="text" id="guessField" class="guessField" autofocus>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit guess" class="guessSubmit">
  </div>



  <div class="resultParas">
    <p class="guesses"></p>
    <p class="lastResult"></p>
    <p class="lowOrHi"></p>
  </div>

</body>
<script>
  // Your JavaScript goes here
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

  var guesses = document.querySelector(".guesses");
  var lastResult = document.querySelector(".lastResult");
  var lowOrHi = document.querySelector(".lowOrHi");

  var guessField = document.querySelector(".guessField");
  var guessSubmit = document.querySelector(".guessSubmit");
  var test; //used for creating new reset button
  var count = 1; // counter for counting user input

  function checkGuess() {
    //alert('checkGuess is called');
    var value = Number(guessField.value);
    if (count === 1) {
      guesses.textContent = "Previous guesses :"
    }
    guesses.textContent += value + ' ';



    if (value === randomNumber) {
      lastResult.textContent = "congratulation u successfully guessed the number";
      lastResult.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      lowOrHi.textContent = "";
      left = 1;
      setGameOver();
    } else if (count === 10) {
      lastResult.textContent = "game over"
      lastResult.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      left = 1;
      setGameOver();
    } else {

      lastResult.textContent = "WRONG";
      lastResult.style.backgroundColor = "red";

      if (value < randomNumber) {
        lowOrHi.textContent = "too low";
      } else {
        lowOrHi.textContent = "too high";
      }
    }

    count++;
    guessField.value = '';

  }

  guessSubmit.addEventListener("click", checkGuess);


  function setGameOver() {
    guessField.disabled = true;
    guessSubmit.disabled = true;
    test = document.createElement('button');
    test.textContent = "restart game";
    document.body.appendChild(test);
    test.addEventListener('click', resetGame);
  }



  function resetGame() {
    count = 1;

    var resetParas = document.querySelectorAll('.resultParas');
    for (var i = 0; i < resetParas.length; i++) {
      resetParas[i].textContent = '';
    }

    guessField.disabled = false;
    guessSubmit.disabled = false;
    guessField.value = '';
    lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'white';

    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

    test.parentNode.removeChild(test);
  }
</script>

</html>
```

But when i try to run the game and use the reset game button to restart the game then i am not able to manipulate guesses,lastResult and lowOrHi elements using textContent and backgroundColor properties.

Comment: Please recommend any other useful resources for learning javascript.

Comment: Making this a code snippet would allow us to try to execute what you've down.  The main thing you need to do is to cut this down to a [mcve].  Then everyone can focus on what isn't working.

Comment: Did you try using `.value` instead of `.textContent`

Comment: No one is going to have the patience to go through all your code. You already have access to the tutorial code, why don't you step through it line by line trying to find your fault?

Answer (score 0):

Your blanking out everything inside .resultParas..  And this will include all you `<p>` tags.  IOW: after doing that they have disappeared from the DOM, you can see this say in chrome inspector that .resultPara's after clicking `reset game` is now blank, and all your `p` tags have gone.

I think what you really want to do, is blank out the children  (the p tags)..

You don't need querySelectorAll either, as in your case there is only the one.

```
var resetParas = document.querySelector('.resultParas');
for(var i = 0 ; i < resetParas.children.length ; i++) {
  resetParas.children[i].textContent = '';
}
```